# Как сделать цикл в цикле в handlebarsjs?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Как сделать проход each для объекта и потом пройтись циклом по value свойств объекта(например если это массив)?

```
{{#each object1 }}
 {{@key}} {{this}}

  {{#each ../this }}
      {{@key2}}
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

Comment: Внутренний `each` должен проходить по `object1` или по какому-то его свойству?

Comment: по каждому свойству. То есть @key и value есть, надо по value пройти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно, я совсем не понимаю, в чем именно проблема. Обход свойств во вложенном массиве делается элементарно.

**Данные**:

```
{ 
    data: {
        foo: {
            foo1: 'f1',
            foo2: 'f2'
        },
        bar: {
            bar1: 'b1',
            bar2: 'b2'
        }
    }
}
```

**Шаблон**:

```
{{#each data}}
    {{@key}}

    {{#each this}}
        {{@key}} {{this}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

**Вывод**:

```
 foo
      foo1 f1
      foo2 f2
 bar
      bar1 b1
      bar2 b2
```

Comment: А вот тут как пройти?:

        var data = {
            GR: {
                a: 1,
                b: 2
            },
            HT: {
                a: 3,
                b: 4,
        }

Comment: @manking, Обновил ответ